# Another weird behavior of css How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

Another weird behavior of css:

I have this structure and apperently I should get the strong tag `ltr` and everything else in p tag `rtl`:

```css
p {
     direction: rtl; 
}

strong {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
<strong>This should be to right side. این باید سمت راست باشد</strong>
</p>
```

But it ignores the style of strong tag - how can I fix this?

Comment: There must be some other CSS script cutting this line out. Try using !important.

Comment: My code is simple look at it again .. there is not other css style.. I used important too ..

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

> For the direction property to have any effect on inline-level elements, the unicode-bidi property's value must be embed or override.

So you *could* do something like this…

```css
p {
     direction: rtl; 
     unicode-bidi: bidi-override; /* Dirty great hack; don't do this */
}

strong {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
<strong>This should be to right side. این باید سمت راست باشد</strong>
</p>
```

**However** [the documentation for that property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) says:

> Warning: This property is intended for Document Type Definition (DTD) designers. Web designers and similar authors should not override it.

---

The real issue here is that `strong` is an inline element. It can start in the middle of a line. It can word wrap.

There's not really a "left" or "right" because it isn't a solid block.

```css
p {
     direction: rtl; 
}

strong {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
Text outside the strong. Text outside the strong. Text outside the strong.  <strong>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  این باید سمت راست باشد این باید سمت راست باشد این باید سمت راست باشد این باید سمت راست باشد این باید سمت راست باشد این باید سمت راست باشد</strong>. Text outside the strong. Text outside the strong. Text outside the strong. 
</p>
```

You *could* set `display: block` on the strong element, but it would make more sense to just style the paragraph itself.

Comment: None of the snippets work , did you see that ?

Comment: @SaraRee — They aren't supposed to *work*. They're supposed to demonstrate the conceptual problem with what you are asking for. Read to the end. Pay attention to the final paragraph.